# Cannot solve CORS Blocking Issue between React and Node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, axios, cors

I've been working on website using react.js in the front and node.js in the back and whenever I send a patch request, I am getting Blocked by CORS like the following:
"Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:4000/admin/appointment/63efc1cc0eecac628d653b65' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Method PATCH is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Methods in preflight response.

Appointments.js:50 AxiosError {message: 'Network Error', name: 'AxiosError', code: 'ERR_NETWORK', config: {…}, request: XMLHttpRequest, …}
xhr.js:247

PATCH http://localhost:4000/admin/appointment/63efc1cc0eecac628d653b65 net::ERR_FAILED"

My code for front end using axios to handle request is:

```
axiosInstance
  .patch(
    `/admin/appointment/${id}`,
    { status: "Finished" },
    {
      headers: {
        Authorization: token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      },
    }
  )
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res.data);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

and My code from node js is:

```
router.patch('/appointment/:id', auth, async (req, res) => {
try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const AppointmentToUpdate = req.body;
    const updatedAppointment = await appointmentModel.update({ _id: id }, number, { runValidators: true });
    res.json(updatedAppointment);
}catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err.message);
}
```

})

and I have already installed cors and required it in my backend:

```
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();
mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost:27017/frontdesk`);
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "*",
    methods: "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  })
);
```

I've should mention that I used other methods like login "POST" request and "GET" request and all are working fine

Answer (score 0):

Replace cors with the following code. It should solve your issue.

```
const options = {
  "origin": "*",
  "methods": "GET,HEAD,PUT,PATCH,POST,DELETE",
  "preflightContinue": false,
  "optionsSuccessStatus": 204
}
app.use(cors(options));
```

Comment: Thank you, now it's working. When I added "preflightContinue": false, "optionsSuccessStatus": 204, The CORS error disappeared